# Получить и проверить параметры командной строки

Tags: python

Напишите программу, которая берет из параметров командной строки два целочисленных аргумента и выводит на экран их сумму.
В случае любой ошибки (некорректное количество аргументов, аргументы не того типа и т.д.) следует вывести число 0.

Не совсем понимаю, как взять параметры их командной строки, подскажите пожалуйста.

Comment: a = input().split(" ")

print(a[1] + a[2])
так?

Comment: @entithat, какое отношение имеет `input()` к этому вопросу?

Comment: @Qwertiy, а я подумал, что в задачах такого типа обычно имеют ввиду ввод в консоль)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Делается через модуль sys, причем [0] - имя файла.

**filename.py**:

```
import sys
num1 = int(sys.argv[1])
num2 = int(sys.argv[2])
```

Если запустить `python filename.py 1 2`, тогда num1 = 1, num2 - 2